# Flutter - In a CustomScrollView how to prevent a scrolled Widget from being draw behind a pined Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

Hi I am an Android developer and I started to port my app to Flutter.

In Android when you have a CoordinatorLayout with an Expanded AppBar and a Scrollable content when the content is scrolled is not visible behind the Appbar.

This gif is the behaivior on Android and what I want to achieve on Flutter.
The appbar and the scrolled content backgorund's are transparent to let the user to see the background image, but the scrolled content don't pass throught the appbar)

[image: This is what I want to do in Flutter]

In flutter I can replicate this Layout sucesfully, but the problem is the scroll content is draw behind the AppBar.

[image]

**Is there a way to not draw the scroll content behind the appbar?**

This is my code on flutter:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Background(image: 'assets/images/fondo_horario.webp'),
    Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
            title: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                          "HORARIO DE CURSOS DEL CICLO 2019B",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                  Text(
                          "TOTAL DE CRÉDITOS: 52",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 9, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: BarraHorario(),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: CeldasHorario(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Why don’t you just set a fixed color of your app bar to an opaque one instead of transparent? IMO a transparent AppBar should allow its behind to be seen, like its properly happening to you.

Comment: Because this is the behaivior I want to show to the users.

Comment: I don’t get it. But if you want to hide the back, use an opaque color instead to your AppBar. The end result will be the same, right?

Comment: "Put an opaque background color and problem solved" ... it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: But that’s the solution for your problem. Mind to explain better your use case?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo He wants to see the background image through the `AppBar`

Answer (score 0):

I think u can try to put a new Stack into your old Stack.

The old Stack contains the background image.

The new Stack will be set Colors.transparent and contain your appbar and Scrollable content. So 2 of them will be transparent with your background image but the appbar not transparent with your content.

Hope it works.

Comment: Can you explain it a little more please. I have searched for an answer and tried different options all day.

Comment: Sorry i forget to add this: The old Stack contains the background image and the new Stack. The back ground first then  the new Stack.

Comment: If your new Stack set background transparent then your Appbar and Content will be transparent with your background right? But in the new Stack don't set transparent for your Appbar so the Appbar will not be transparent with your Content

Comment: In the new Stack don't set transparent for your Appbar